# Best practice: Passing attribute parameter through a few descendant directives, or passing controller directly to descendant?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a parent directive with variable 'a' on its scope, as scope.a. I would like to pass scope.a to a descendant directive through a child directive.

Is it better practice to create a controller on the parent with a getA() function that can be used directly in the descendant directive, or is it also OK to pass scope.a via attribute to the descendant directive through the intermediate child directive?

Or perhaps there is a different way of doing this that is even better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the nature of your data. If the intermediate directive has nothing to do with that data and its sole purpose by getting it is to pass it on, then it sounds to me it shouldn't do that.

You can also use a service to store that data and fetch it from your last child directive in a similar way it's done to share data between controllers.

What you said also works, using "require" attribute in the child directive. That's intended to communicate between directives. But is it also possible to use this child directive independent of the (grand)parent directive? If the answer to this question is yes, then you should hold the data in a service to be able to fetch it regardless of the DOM structure. If the answer is no, the I guess this method will do fine.

Comment: Thanks! I think that covered it well.

Comment: In my case, the intermediate directive does, in theory, have to do with the data being passed through it, but currently it does not utilize the data. It is possible that in the future the intermediate directive will use the data. What would you suggest in my case?

Comment: @code2b I tend to keep directive variables to a minimum, meaning if they're not currently required I don't declare them. Personally I would only use it on the intermediate directive when I actually have to. Until then, I'd use one of the other 2, to your choice :)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the feedback.